# Is there a map API that'll give me a list of names of all the places that are visible on the map at that moment?

Tags: maps, openstreetmap

With the least zoom, the names of only certain countries are displayed on the map. As the user increases zoom names of cities appear and then localities and major roads. Finally we get names at the street level.

I'd like these names to be available to my app as the user changes zoom level. Is it possible to get a list of the names that are currently visible? Is there an API that lets me do this?

I've looked around quite a bit but didn't find much help. I would like it if it's possible with Google/Bing maps but any other map that offers the above functionality might work too.

For what it's worth, I'm trying to make a web app in Javascript.

**Example**:
When the user starts, the zoom level is 0 and this is shown:
[image]

I'd like to get the names of countries and water bodies ([India, China, Iran, Arabian sea, ...]).

When the user zooms we'd end up with this:
[image]

Now I'd like to get the names of all the streets, businesses and the city ([Freedom park, HCG, Chinnaswamy stadium, ...]).

Essentially, all the names that are visible on the map at that moment. Just an array of strings would be fine, but I wouldn't say no to any additional information that comes along with it either – such as what a string represents (street/river/city/country/...).